# COMException when trying to get application pools using ServerManager

Tags: c#, iis, administration, servermanager, remote-administration

When I try to get the list of IIS application pools from a remote server using the following code

```
List<ApplicationPool> appPools;

using (ServerManager serverManager = ServerManager.OpenRemote("XXX")) {
  appPools = serverManager.ApplicationPools.ToList();
}
```

I get an exception:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800706BA): Retrieving the COM
class factory for remote component with CLSID
{2B72133B-3F5B-4602-8952-803546CE3344} from machine XXX failed due to the
following error: 800706ba.
```

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Turns out the problem can be fixed by adding an appropriate rule in the Firewall:

- rule type: inbound
- rule type: custom
- program: %systemroot%\system32\dllhost.exe
- protocol: TCP
- local port: RPC Dynamic Ports
- remote port: All Ports
- action: allow connection
- profile: domain

The above solution was inspired by this thread: [Windows Firewall blocking OAB connections](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/e8948639-e8f1-4062-946a-6ed67c491d43/windows-firewall-blocking-oab-connections).

Comment: After hours of searching, this is what fixed my problem.

Comment: That did it! Here's some PowerShell to create the rule.



`New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "RPC Dynamic Ports" -Enabled:True -Profile:Domain -Direction:Inbound -Action:Allow -Protocol "TCP" -Program "%systemroot%\system32\dllhost.exe"`