# ApplicationPools For Remote Server

Tags: c#, iis-8, application-pool, servermanager

I am trying to get a list of all the app pools for a remote server. Trying to execute my code I get this error:

> Retrieving the COM class factory for remote component with CLSID {2B72133B-3F5B-4602-8952-803546CE3344} from machine '{ServerName}' failed due to the following error: 800706ba

I looked at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21092050/comexception-when-trying-to-get-application-pools-using-servermanager) and followed this [answer](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/001ca054-b7da-46e5-b44d-1162e52c60a9/exchange-2007-sp3-rollup-1-emc-error-retrieving-the-com-class-factory-for-remote-component-with?forum=exchangesvrdeploylegacy) but doesn't seem to work at all.

**CODE:**

```
public static ICollection<AppPoolModel> GetServerAppPools(string serverName)
{
    var appPoolList = new List<AppPoolModel>();

    using (var server = ServerManager.OpenRemote(serverName))
    {
        var appPools = server.ApplicationPools;

        foreach (var appPool in appPools)
        {
            appPoolList.Add(new AppPoolModel {
                Name = appPool.Name,
                AutoStart = appPool.AutoStart,
                ManagedRuntimeVersion = appPool.ManagedRuntimeVersion
            });
        }
    }
    return appPoolList;
}
```

The remote server uses IIS8 and it son a Windows Server 2012 R2

Comment: This link has good information on the error code: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/systemcenter/en-US/6a63e0e2-97d0-4d84-a1dd-0c7d1a2981ff/error-code-800706ba?forum=operationsmanagermgmtpacks